# What is an excution of a distributed algorithm from mathematical point of view?

Tags: algorithm, math, distributed-computing, execution

I have a distributed algorithm for mobile ad hoc networks. How can I express the execution of the algorithm from a mathematical point of view? is it a tuple ? or is it a set of time instants during which the algorithm is executed?

Comment: Let's start with something simpler. How would you model a serial algorithm mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a universally accepted or a "one-size-fits-all" model for the execution of distributed algorithms. Below are some possible starting points (but only that: just starting points) for exploring the issue:

- H. J. Boehm, [Reordering Constraints for Pthread-Style Locks](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2005/HPL-2005-217.pdf), 2005
- The page on [Temporal logic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic) from Wikipedia

Regarding the issue of what an *instant* means for distributed algorithms, you may want to read L. Lamport, [Time, clocks, and ordering of events in a distributed system](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/time-clocks.pdf), 1978.